# Bootstrapper for clickonce custom package is not properly calculating the installconditions

Tags: clickonce, bootstrapper

I am trying to build a custom package for odbcsqldriver 13 in order to add it to prerequisites and force the clickonce project to install accordingly. I am in one package added the x86 version and the x64. The install conditions when the prerequisite is about to install are not properly evaluated or i am missing something. 
the package has the following installconditions

```
<InstallChecks>
    <RegistryCheck Property="OS64" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" Value="CommonFilesDir" />
</InstallChecks>
```

```
<InstallConditions>
    <ByPassIf Property="OS64" Compare="ValueExists" />
</InstallConditions>
```

and it is for the x86 version which is not supposed to install if the machine is running 64 bit windows
and for the x64 it is

```
<InstallConditions>
    <ByPassIf Property="OS64" Compare="ValueNotExists" />
</InstallConditions>
```

At the installation in an 64bit machine is initiating although the OS64 property is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files it tries to install the x86 version of the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the InstallConditions at the ByPassIf. I was writing the ByPassIf with capital "P" and it should be BypassIf.